# Typescript : How can I get input data from iFrame in ionic

Tags: typescript, ionic2

I have ionic page witch call external iframe payment page. this iframe has it own operation and then return the result in the frame it self, (like redirect secure payment page)

I open the page in frame like

```html
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-label>Result :</ion-label>
  <iframe id="payment-frame" width="100%" height="100%" [src]="url" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</ion-content>
```

and in ts file I tried to get the input like

```
var script = (<HTMLScriptElement[]><any>document.getElementsByName('Result'))[0];
console.log(script);
```

// the input is null

and then I tried to get the frame first then get the element inside like

```
var inputValue = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('payment-frame').contentWindow.document.getElementById('Result'));
```

// it says that the content windows does not exist in HTMLElement.

How can I get the 'Result' element from external iframe page? any one can help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think that you can use postMessage() to communicate https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

try it :)

i will try to create a plunk a bit later if there will be need for that